# Notify/Log failed uploads to txt file

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, cmd

I have a batch file on my local server which uploads files from different folders to a cloud storage, I would like to know how can I come up with a script which will log an entry to a text file me whenever a specific file from a specific folder fails or doesn't upload (if possible) or if it can notify me, so I can manually push the failed file myself.

the batch file script goes `aws s3 sync q:\xxx\Case s3://xxx/xxx/Case`

Looking around I have been told I can use PowerShell scripts but I never actually used it so I wouldn't know where to start, if there are any other options please let me know.

Comment: if you already use batch, don't make things complicate by adding another tool just add few lines in your batch to write out to some file when error happens; depends on complexity of your batch can be function or just simple 2&1>logfile; for notifications I would suggest some script (as scheduled task) parsing that logfile for err, and when happens - send e-mail.

Comment: @Vairis Thanks for your help, how would I go exactly to create this function within the script? I'm new to the whole batch file process I'm currently trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the aws application throws a error, with a batch file to append just errors would be something like:

```
aws s3 sync q:\xxx\Case s3://xxx/xxx/Case 2>> C:\examplefilename.txt
```

With PowerShell you could use a try/catch statement

```
try {
aws s3 sync q:\xxx\Case s3://xxx/xxx/Case
} catch {
$error[0] | out-file C:\examplefilename.txt -append
}
```

Or if you wanted an email notification on an error it would something like this:

```
try {
aws s3 sync q:\xxx\Case s3://xxx/xxx/Case
} catch {
send-mailmessage -to example@example.org -from script@example.org -body $error[0] -subject "AWS Error" -smtpserver yourmailserver@example.org
}
```